Mongoose duplicate key: _id
As the title suggests, my mongoose call is somehow creating a duplicate _id: ObjectId().
This is the only schema that does that and there is no _id field in the schema.

const PurchaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  amount: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  company: { type: String, required: true },
  poBox: { type: String },
  billingAddress: { type: String, required: true },
  billingCity: { type: String, required: true },
  billingState: { type: String, required: true },
  billingZipCode: { type: String },
  shippingAddress: { type: String, required: true },
  shippingCity: { type: String, required: true },
  shippingState: { type: String, required: true },
  shippingZipCode: { type: String },
  shippingZipcode: { type: String },
  repPhone: { type: String },
  repEmail: { type: String },
  attn: { type: String },
  tier: { type: String, required: true },
  officeId: { type: String, required: true },
  cart: { type: Object, required: true },
  extraDetails: { type: String },
  agreement: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  accountNumber: { type: String },
  date: { type: Date, default: () => Date().now, immutable: true },
});

Here is the error i receive.
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: **REDACTED** index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('6605b8d3570e447569d56dde') }
    **REDACTED** {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { _id: 1 },
  keyValue: { _id: new ObjectId('6605b8d3570e447569d56dde') },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

I can verify that it keep creating the same exact _id every single time.
UPDATE
const Purchase = new Suneva_Purchase({
      ...userDetails,
      ...companyDetails,
      amount: price,
      cart: cart,
      repEmail: repEmail,
      repPhone: repPhone,
      tier: tier,
      officeId: officeId,
      shippingZipCode: userDetails.shippingZipcode,
    });

    console.log(Purchase);

const savedPurchase = await Purchase.save();

Console log results, same _id every time no matter what the input information is
{
 ...correct information,
  _id: new ObjectId('6605b8d3570e447569d56dde'),
  __v: 0
}


Where and how do you get the error?

When i await Purchase.save()

Share the code where you do the await Purchase.save(). Mongoose automatically adds an _id property to each document.

Does this answer your question? E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose

@jQueeny Updated the question with the information you asked for

@ray no the _id field is always a unique key either created by Mongo itself or Mongoose.

I suspect the because you are using spread syntax for ...userDetails and ...companyDetails that the  _id: ObjectId('6605b8d3570e447569d56dde') exists in one of those objects therefore breaking the unique index constraint on _id. Or have you just used ... to condense your code on here?
